# How to set up external DNS?

Tags: domain-name-system, reverse-dns

I have few appliances that are HTTP/HTTPS managed and assigned PUBLIC IP ADDRESSES and I need to set up DNS name resolution so I can access externally by it's name. How to set up external DNS?

Comment: 1. Purchase a domain name. 2. Create DNS records. 3. Profit!

Answer (score 0):

Look at a hosted DNS provider such as AWS Route 53 or GoDaddy.

You then can create one or more records mapping "www.yourstuff.com" to 10.0.0.1.

Comment: I would like to try use my domain controller server, which is DNS server for my internal network.

Comment: I think you are confusing two things - one is having a DNS server with the records in it. This is something you can do on your DC no problem. The other is having OTHER people be able to resolve it. That requires registration with a service provider saying "for mysite.com go to 8.8.8.8" where 8.8.8.8 is your DNS server.

Comment: Right, that is why I am asking to figure out what should I do to make it work. My service provider is Comcast, so do I have to call them and ask to associate my internal web site name with public IP? And which public IP they should associate it with?

Answer (score 0):

You can create appliances A records to the DNS, the IP addresses should be the public ones. Once that is ready add CNAME records and point them to the actual hosts.

Comment: Just one question further: do you have internal and external dns?

Comment: He said in the original post it was external

Comment: @HumbertoCastellon I do have interanl DNS on my LAN, and I am trying to figure out how to access externally my web site on the LAN?

Comment: Ok, one more thing: do you have a registered domain name?